# UWP ComboBox no longer has open/close animations (build 14393)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10

I'm styling a ComboBox in my UWP app and I'm trying to come up with a solution to the missing dropdown animations in the control.

Looks like the open/close animations were removed with the Anniversary Update, I mean, they are still played in the Settings app for some reason, but I no longer see them in both my own app, in the Calculator or any other UWP app compiled for Windows 10 14393.

This is what I see in the ComboBox template:

```
<VisualStateGroup x:Name="DropDownStates">
  <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
    <Storyboard>
      <SplitOpenThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
                               ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
                               OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}"
                               OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}"/>
    </Storyboard>
  </VisualState>
  <VisualState x:Name="Closed">
    <Storyboard>
      <SplitCloseThemeAnimation OpenedTargetName="PopupBorder"
                                ClosedTargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                OffsetFromCenter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOffset}"
                                OpenedLength="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DropDownOpenedHeight}"/>
    </Storyboard>
  </VisualState>
</VisualStateGroup>
```

Those `SplitOpenThemeAnimation` animations are not really animations since they behave like a setter, their effect is immediate and not animated at all.

I was wondering if there was a simple way to restore the previous animations (maybe I'm just missing a simple option/parameter to add in the XAML?) without having to manually mess with the template and write my own clip/transform animations, which is something I'd prefer not to do here, since should MS change the template again in a future build I'd have done all for nothing.

Any suggestions here? Thanks!

**EDIT:** for the moment here's the workaround I'm using, but I'd like to have something that keeps the slide/clipping animation as the original animation did.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Opened">
  <Storyboard>
    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Popup"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                     From="0"
                     To="1"
                     Duration="0:0:0.2">
    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
      <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
  </DoubleAnimation>
  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PopupTransform"
                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.Y)"
                   From="-20"
                   To="0"
                   Duration="0:0:0.2">
    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
      <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
  </DoubleAnimation>
  <!--Original SplitOpenAnimation here-->
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs on developer's machines that have disabled animations on a system level. The built-in animations obey this system setting. You might double-check.

[image]

Comment: Hello Jerry, unfortunately that's not the issue (that option is on for me). As I've stated, I see the same behavior in both my app, other 3rd party apps and system apps too (like Calculator, or even the Settings app). It's the template of the ComboBox itself that got changed with the Anniversary Update (check the generic.xaml file for the build 14393). I honestly don't know why the UI team made this choice and I was just wondering if there was a better way to revert that. Of course though, built-in animations would be better than having to manually reimplement them like I'm doing now. Thanks!